# Kong + JWT Excluding endpoints from authorization

Tags: jwt, endpoint, kong

I am using Kong and the JWT plugin to authenticate my upstream services. I have a use case where i would like to expose an endpoint in one of the services without having Kong authenticate against it. I was wondering if there is any way to specify exclusion patterns to let Kong know to ignore authentication for this endpoint?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kong looks at the configured APIs in order of length. So it should be possible (without have tested it) that you use a longer `uri` (the one you want to make publicly accessible) without the JWT plugin, while keeping your current endpoint with the JWT plugin.

For example, if your current configuration is on `/myApi` and the path you want to make public is `/myApi/login`, then add an API on the latter without configuring the JWT on it.