# How to ignore the url with a performance way in spring gateway

Tags: java, gateway

I have define a `JwtAuthenticationGatewayFilter` in spring gateway, now I define a list that store the url need to ignore with token valid like this:

```
public static Predicate<ServerHttpRequest> isApiSecured;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initExcludePath(){
       isApiSecured = r -> {
            List<String> excludeList = loginExcludeUrl.getExclude();
            return excludeList.stream()
                .noneMatch(uri -> r.getURI().getPath().equals(uri));};
    }
```

the `loginExcludeUrl.getExclude()` will get the ignore urls list(hundreds or thousands). when in the filter using this function to know ignore the url or not:

```
if (isApiSecured.test(request)) {
     return authImpl(request, exchange, chain);
}
```

I am worry about when the ignore list increase, the whole website performance will slow down because every request should apply the list filter. is there any better way to ignore the url? Some of the url config like this:

```
login-check-path:
  exclude: 
    - /post/user/reg
    - /login
    - /post/user/login
    - /post/user/plugin/login
    - /post/user/sms
    - /post/auth/access_token/refresh
    - /post/auth/refresh_token/refresh
    - /post/article/newstories
    - /post/article/originalstories
    - /post/article/officialstories
    - /post/article/share
    - /post/article/read
    - /post/article/detail
    - /post/wechat/util/verifyWxToken
    - /post/wechat/login/getQRCodeUrl
    - /post/wechat/login/wxCallBack
    - /post/alipay/login/alipayCallBack
    - /post/alipay/login/getQRCodeUrl
    - /post/alipay/notification/v1/alipaySeverNotification
    - /post/websocket
    - /manage/admin/user/login
    - /dict/user/plugin/login
    - /dict/user/login
    - /dict/auth/access_token/refresh
    - /dict/auth/refresh_token/refresh
    - /fortune/user/login
    - /fortune/user/guest/login
    - /fortune/user/sms
    - /fortune/user/reg/verify
    - /fortune/auth/access-token/refresh
    - /tik/user/login
    - /tik/user/guest/login
    - /tik/user/sms
    - /tik/user/reg/verify
```

Comment: Are that hundreds or thousands urls, web assets like css, js, etc ?

Comment: I have pasted some of the config that shows the ignore urls  will increase to hundreds or thousands urls in the future @JRichardsz

Answer (score 1):

Since you are **centralizing all the requests** of your company **in one gateway**, the only way to add or exclude some urls is **mapping one by one** and then the core should **ask one by one** if the incoming url should be secured or not.

### Apply jwt on specific routes

As example, in case of **Kong Gateway** if you don't [add explicitly the route](https://medium.com/@far3ns/kong-the-microservice-api-gateway-526c4ca0cfa6), no body could consume the route because don't have public access enabled

In the other way, you can create the Api and then on each API you can decide to add the JWT plugin or not.

Sources:

- https://groups.google.com/g/konglayer/c/Q18uZGFhLhw/m/Ec9fUEbMBwAJ
- [Kong + JWT Excluding endpoints from authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48601959/kong-jwt-excluding-endpoints-from-authorization)

> **So you don't need to add the exclusion one by one.**

I think you could add only the routes you need using this yaml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: employeeModule
        uri: http://localhost:8081/
        predicates:
        - Path=/employee/**
      - id: consumerModule
        uri: http://localhost:8082/
        predicates:
        - Path=/consumer/**
```

Source: https://www.javainuse.com/spring/cloud-gateway

### Use regex to exclude

Use regex could speed up the comparation

You could try something like the regex or matchers used in spring security:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41381822/3957754
- [Spring Security exclude url patterns in security annotation configurartion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767205/spring-security-exclude-url-patterns-in-security-annotation-configurartion)
- [Regex doesn't match antMatcher URL pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57119334/regex-doesnt-match-antmatcher-url-pattern)
- [regexMatcher for URL with query parameters in Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51578696/regexmatcher-for-url-with-query-parameters-in-spring-security)

So the code could look like this (not tested):

```
List<String> excludeRegexList = loginExcludeUrl.getExclude();

return excludeRegexList.stream()
.noneMatch(
regexPattern -> r.getURI().getPath().matches(regexPattern)
);};
```

### Use a no relation or in-memory db

Instead to load the list of exclusions , you could use mongodb or redis, so you will be able to handle a lot of exclusions and query them to decide if the incoming url should be protected or not

### Use another api gateway

You could use another gateway only for public or non-protected routes. You could even use a simple nginx because these endpoints should not be protected

---

I hope one of these options helps you